# 3.2.2 Anyway to taper volume scatter so the boundary is less defined/more blended; cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

My volume scatter 'fog box'/cube has a hard edge that I would like to soften.  Is than an easy way to do that?  I am trying multiple 'fog boxes' with decreasing density but am wondering if I could do anything here with GN.  I also tried subdividing my cube and altering the shape to be less flat at the top but that seems to be a bit too fiddly.

Too sharp, want this transition to be softer, to fade out more
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a *Gradient Texture*, separated on the Z-axis to soften the falloff. The *Invert Node* is not necessary (you can invert with the *ColorRamp* instead), I just put it there to make it more clear what's happening. I usually like to warp the vectors of the gradient with a *Noise Texture* first, to give a more natural look:

[image: FogWarp]